# Hibernate looking for column in wrong table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have this query that works in native SQL and Hibernate in Java.

It breaks with error that says

> could not resolve property: `entityName` …

(or amount) when I use pageable to sort results for one of those two columns.

Also Hibernate fails to map items to `Page<McConsumerBalanceEntity>` and returns `pageimpl` of objects so I am using `List<Object[]>` to map items manually which works.

Hibernate version is 5.3.7. Database is PostgreSQL 10.5. Spring Boot is  2.1.0

```
@Query(
        value = "select csr.id, csr.firstName, csr.lastName, " +
                "sum (case " +
                    "when acs.type = 'PAYMENT' then acs.amount " +
                    "else -acs.amount " +
                "end) as amount, " +
                "me.id as entityId, " +
                "me.name as entityName " +
                "from McConsumerEntity csr, EbAccountConsumerEntity acs, McEntity me " +
                "where csr.idMcEntity in :childEntityIds " +
                "and csr.idMcEntity = me.id " +
                "and csr.id = acs.idMcConsumer " +
                "and amount > 0 " +
                "group by csr.id, me.id, me.name ")
```

```
public class McConsumerBalanceEntityGenerated implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 217L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_null", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_null",
            sequenceName = "sequence_null", allocationSize = 100)
    protected Long id;



    @Column(name = "amount")
    protected BigDecimal amount;


    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    protected Long entityId;


    @Column(name = "entity_name")
    protected String entityName;


    @Column(name = "first_name")
    protected String firstName;


    @Column(name = "last_name")
    protected String lastName;




    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    public McConsumerBalanceEntityGenerated() {
        super();
    }

/*
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    private McConsumerBalanceEntity(Builder builder) {
        this.id = builder.id;
    }
*/

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    

    /**
     * Access method for the amount property.
     *
     * @return the current value of the amount property
     */
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of the amount property.
     *
     * @param aAmount the new value of the version property
     */
    public void setAmount(BigDecimal aAmount) {
        this.amount = aAmount;
    }


    /**
     * Access method for the entityId property.
     *
     * @return the current value of the entityId property
     */
    public Long getEntityId() {
        return this.entityId;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of the entityId property.
     *
     * @param aEntityId the new value of the version property
     */
    public void setEntityId(Long aEntityId) {
        this.entityId = aEntityId;
    }


    /**
     * Access method for the entityName property.
     *
     * @return the current value of the entityName property
     */
    public String getEntityName() {
        return this.entityName;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of the entityName property.
     *
     * @param aEntityName the new value of the version property
     */
    public void setEntityName(String aEntityName) {
        this.entityName = aEntityName;
    }


    /**
     * Access method for the firstName property.
     *
     * @return the current value of the firstName property
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of the firstName property.
     *
     * @param aFirstName the new value of the version property
     */
    public void setFirstName(String aFirstName) {
        this.firstName = aFirstName;
    }


    /**
     * Access method for the lastName property.
     *
     * @return the current value of the lastName property
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }



    /**
     * Sets the value of the lastName property.
     *
     * @param aLastName the new value of the version property
     */
    public void setLastName(String aLastName) {
        this.lastName = aLastName;
    }



/*    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static class Builder {

        private Long id;

        public Builder setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public McConsumerBalanceEntity build() {
            return new McConsumerBalanceEntity(this);
        }
    }*/

}
```

Comment: you mean in Hibernate does not work perhaps? you wrote that in native SQL works and also in Hibernate works

Comment: We need to see the definition for `McConsumerBalanceEntity`.  Note that `List<Object>` is probably the standard way to go here, given that your query does not logically return a single entity.

Comment: @Rollerball it works if I don't sort by those 2 columns (when I sort by id)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen McConsumerBalanceEntity is extended from McConsumerBalanceEntityGenerated and implements Serializable.
I will post code now

Comment: How does the repository method look like? Also, please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states that could not resolve property: entityName, which means the column does not exists in the Entity which it is trying to fetch. And I can observe that in your SQL native query, You are trying to fetch it from me.Name and as per the entity you have provided it is present in McConsumerBalanceEntityGenerated. So try joining this Entity and fetch the entityName from this table/Entity.

Comment: This Generated entity is `@MappedSuperclass` and extended one is `@Entity` but none of them is `@Table` so I don't think I can join it plus It's not table in DB. What I am trying here is to return table as temporary by combining tose 3, in one that is not in DB, as data to be parsed on FE. I hope this explained a bit.

Comment: Also, the me.name I am trying to fetch is present in McEntity so I can fetch it from there without joining entity you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying which Hibernate version your are using or what database, so everyone here has to guess about these questions and many more. If you ever want to receive good answers, consider giving more details in your questions or pay a consultant to do the work for you. The way you are asking questions here is as if you were asking a mechanic "My Ford makes a strange noise when driving fast, what's the problem?".

Having said that, I'll start guessing by assuming you are using Oracle. Maybe you are running into an issue similar to the following one: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/issues-in-migrating-from-hibernate-5-3-3-to-5-3-4/5679/2

> Also Hibernate fails to map items to Page and returns pageimpl of objects so I am using List<Object[]> to map items manually which works.

That is expected. Hibernate does not do "inference" or anything like that. If you want `McConsumerBalanceEntity` to be returned, then use a JPQL constructor expression.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. Hibernate version is 5.3.7. Database is PostgreSQL 10.5. Spring Boot is  2.1.0